# Is it possible to auto git add files with VS Code as soon as they're created?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'd like to know if it's possible to `git add` files with VS Code as soon as they're created?

I know that it's possible with WebStorm, but I'm still looking for a solution on VSCode.

Comment: I came here looking for exactly that. What Webstorm does would be ideal to ask you if you want to add this new file to git or not.

Comment: Did anyone find way to enable this ? @ThanosDi

Answer (score 0):

No, not without a third-party extension as of writing this. However, it looks like enough have people requested this feature - see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85564) - to move it to the VS Code team's backlog as of January 2020.

Frankly I'm surprised to learn VS Code doesn't support this QoL feature, given it appears every other major IDE does. This likely has something to do with their philosophy of building VS Code as a streamlined code editor rather than a fully-fledged IDE.